# AngularJS not working when i split ng-app and ng-controller

Tags: angularjs

I have this code in html:

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        {{ firstName + " " + lastName}}
    </div>

    <div ng-app="MyApp">
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
             {{ firstName + " " + lastName}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

why doesnt angular work for the second (splitted divs) and works for the first (only one div)?

btw my .js is this:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.firstName = "John";
$scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

Edit: this is what i get on my page:

```
 John Doe
 {{ firstName + " " + lastName}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example you changed the app name to `MyApp`. Change it to `myApp` and it should work.

Comment: I cant believe i had a typo, but strangely it still doesn't work.

Comment: I switched their places and figured out that angular only takes the first ng-app. Anyway thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

An application can have only one `ng-app` directive.

> Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML
>   document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define
>   the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple
>   applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them
>   using angular.bootstrap instead. AngularJS applications cannot be
>   nested within each other.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp